# Tracking goals that happen on 3rd party sites in Google Analytics

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, e-commerce

I have a couple websites where I send traffic to a 3rd party site, where the conversion happens. I've been using a program that lets you install a conversion pixel (basically just an `img` tag) on the third party site's "thank you" page, but would like to move everything over to Google Analytics if possible.

Is it possible to use Google Analytics to track conversions (I guess I'd use "Goals" in Analytics) that happen on a third party site? I've seen a few questions on Stack Overflow about this, but some of the information seems out of date, and ideally I'd like to find a step-by-step guide on how to set this up. It sounds like it would involve iFraming my Analytics code on the 3rd party site's thank you page and making that iFrame's URL the goal, but I guess you need to configure a couple things to make the cross-domain tracking work correctly.

Comment: An iframe would not require cross domain tracking since the content of the  iframe ist hosted on your own domain. Note that an iframe would be pretty much unable to receive data from the page it's embedded in if that page is on a different domain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris, I recommend you to use [Tag Manager](https://www.google.com/tagmanager/) from Google to track practically everything, and without the need of asking the developers to add more tags or HTML code.

From the official site:

> Google Tag Manager is free and easy, leaving more time and money to
>   spend on your marketing campaigns. You manage your tags and configure
>   your applications yourself, with an easy-to-use web interface,
>   rather than forcing you or your IT department to write or rewrite
>   code.

You just need to add an iFrame, which collects the events you define, in the third party site. This iFrame must be present to be able to work. Then you define for each tag an event in the Google Analytics. Both are very well integrated.

Comment: Checking this out now, THANK YOU!